# issue trying to create correlation matrix with nested for() loops

Tags: r, loops, matrix, correlation

I have a data set with election poll data with numeric values 0-10.
 I have 30 columns with these values and I want to compare every column with
 all the other columns in order to create a correlation matrix. 
]
But I keep getting the following error code:

```
 Error in columnlist[i, j] <- cor(feeling_therm[, i], feeling_therm[, j],  : 
      incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Any suggestion on how to get this right? I'm still getting used to the syntax of R.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `cor(election)`. It should create the correlation matrix.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to fix my loop code above as well to make it do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan Werth remarked, `cor(election)` works just fine. However, if you insist on using a for loop you should initialize your matrix as a matrix (including correct dimensions), not as a list:

```
election <- replicate(5, rnorm(n = 100))
election <- as.data.frame(election)

cor_matrix <- matrix(nrow = ncol(election), ncol = ncol(election))

for (i in 1:ncol(election)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(election)) {
    cor_matrix[i,j] <- cor(election[,i], election[,j], use = "complete")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to store values in a **list** then following is an option.

```
n_col <- ncol(election)
electionlist <- as.list(data.frame( matrix(NA, n_col, n_col)))


for (i in 1 : n_col) {
  for (j in 1 : n_col) {
    electionlist[[c(i, j)]] <- cor(election[,i], 
                                election[,j], use = "complete")
  }
}
```